# Why is my vector not adding the struct?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm having problems with the last part of my project on this algorithm. I'm having a problem with the .size() of my vector. It doesn't give me anything. Everytime I try to debug it, it's 0. I don't know if that means that my function is not working properly.

I'm new to programing and I need some help.

Edit1: I've added the new code that is giving me an exception.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <vector>


using namespace System;
using namespace std;


typedef struct Linea {
    int a;
    int q;
    int b;
    int r;
} SLinea;

int algoritmoeuclides(int a,int b)
{
    if (a%b==0)
        return b;
    return algoritmoeuclides(b,a%b);
}

std::pair<int, int>division(int dividendo,int divisor)
{
    int resultado=0;
    int residuo=0;

    residuo=dividendo%divisor;
    resultado=dividendo/divisor;
    std::pair<int, int>retorno;
    retorno.first=resultado;
    retorno.second=residuo;
    return retorno;

}

std::pair<int, int>EuclidesExtendido(int a,int b,vector<SLinea*> aux)
{
    std::pair<int, int> tsqt;
    int q,r,s,t;
    SLinea *var;

    if (b == 0)
        return std::pair<int, int> (1, 0);
    else
    {

        std::pair<int, int>qr = division(a, b);
        q=qr.first;
        r=qr.second;
        std::pair<int, int>st = EuclidesExtendido(b, r,aux);
        s=st.first;
        t=st.second;
    }
    tsqt.first=t;
    tsqt.second=s-q*t;
    var->a=a;
    var->b=b;
    var->q=q;
    var->r=r;
    aux.push_back(var);

    return tsqt;



}
int main()

{
    int a=23;
    int b=120;
    int s,t;
    vector<SLinea*> Ecuacion;


    std::pair<int, int>st=EuclidesExtendido(a,b,Ecuacion);
    s=st.first;
    t=st.second;
    int resultado=algoritmoeuclides(a,b);
    int n=Ecuacion.size();
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {

        printf("%d=%dx%d+%d\n",Ecuacion[i]->a,Ecuacion[i]->b,Ecuacion[i]->q,Ecuacion[i]->r);



    }
    printf("MCD= %d\n ",resultado);
    printf("s=%d  \nt=%d",s,t);
    system("pause");

}
```

---

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <vector>


    using namespace System;
    using namespace std;


    typedef struct Linea {
        int a;
        int q;
        int b;
        int r;
    } SLinea;

    int algoritmoeuclides(int a,int b)
    {
        if (a%b==0)
            return b;
        return algoritmoeuclides(b,a%b);
    }

    std::pair<int, int>division(int dividendo,int divisor)
    {
        int resultado=0;
        int residuo=0;

        residuo=dividendo%divisor;
        resultado=dividendo/divisor;
        std::pair<int, int>retorno;
        retorno.first=resultado;
        retorno.second=residuo;
        return retorno;

    }

    std::pair<int, int>EuclidesExtendido(int a,int b,vector<SLinea> aux)
    {
        std::pair<int, int> tsqt;
        int q,r,s,t;
        SLinea var;

        if (b == 0)
            return std::pair<int, int> (1, 0);
        else
        {

            std::pair<int, int>qr = division(a, b);
            q=qr.first;
            r=qr.second;
            std::pair<int, int>st = EuclidesExtendido(b, r,aux);
            s=st.first;
            t=st.second;
        }
        tsqt.first=t;
        tsqt.second=s-q*t;
        var.a=a;
        var.b=b;
        var.q=q;
        var.r=r;
        aux.push_back(var);

        return tsqt;



    }
    int main()

    {
        int a=23;
        int b=120;
        int s,t;
        vector<SLinea> Ecuacion;


        std::pair<int, int>st=EuclidesExtendido(a,b,Ecuacion);
        s=st.first;
        t=st.second;
        int resultado=algoritmoeuclides(a,b);
        int n=Ecuacion.size();
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {

            printf("%d=%dx%d+%d\n",Ecuacion[i].a,Ecuacion[i].b,Ecuacion[i].q,Ecuacion[i].r);



        }
        printf("MCD= %d\n ",resultado);
        printf("s=%d  \nt=%d",s,t);
        system("pause");

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::pair<int, int> EuclidesExtendido(int a,int b,vector<SLinea> aux)
```

That function takes the parameter `aux` by value, which means that it gets a copy of whatever its used as an argument. I'll let you take it from there...

Comment: yeah but when i try to change everything with * it gives me an exception of memory

Comment: @Giuseppe: That's a vector of pointers, not a pointer to a vector.  The vector is still being copied.

Comment: Try `std::pair<int, int>EuclidesExtendido(int a,int b,vector<SLinea>* aux)`, `aux->push_back(var);`, and then call it with `EuclidesExtendido(a,b,&Ecuacion)`

Comment: @Giuseppe: Now that you got it working, you may want to consider researching C++ references... They are a better alternative than pointers for cases like yours.

Comment: @K-ballo: Debatable.  For operators, and using `const` references as a more efficient version of pass-by-value, certainly.  But using references to allow the function to silently change parameters passed to it is questionable.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Indeed, I had that debate myself. Taking arguments by pointer makes it visible to the caller that the value may change (unless its working with pointers already). However, it also invites `null` to be used and you have to document how your function reacts to null and/or assert on it. But then you realize C++ gives you the same functionality with less problems by implementing an `out(x)` template function, while still using references.

Comment: @BenVoigt, there should be clear documentation if someone else is going to be using it. As far as I see it, if `null` is allowed, use a pointer, and if not, use a reference. The caller should know what the function is supposed to do.

Comment: @chris: A non-`const` reference is much less problematic when the function name suggests mutation, for sure.

Comment: @chris: And when `null` is allowed, only use a pointer it the argument is naturally a pointer. Otherwise, use something like `boost::optional<?>`. But this has gone off-topic enough already...

Comment: @K-ballo, very true. I haven't used boost myself yet (let alone boost::optional), so it didn't come naturally to mind, but it is a very well-organized way of doing things.